# Refine search results on entering location using ajax?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, database, event-handling

I have this textbox in asp.net webform page used to enter a city. On entering some text it provides suggestions just like facebook does of matching results.

I tried these two methods to implement this.

1. I first used onTextChanged event and AJAX and found out it only works when the textbox loses focus. I wanted a solution to work as you type. Advantage of using this was that I could use a database and it would be fast, because no xml files will be transferred in the process.

2.I used ajax, clientside using js. But the problem is the xml containing cities, there states, country is a massive 30MB file. So, it was impossible to use it, so thought of making 26 small xml files of each alphabet out of that big one but still they would be big enough to actually use. So, now I am planning to use 26*26 files containing the cities with same first two alphabets but I think its ineffective way to do what I want.

Is there any other efficient way of accomplishing it? 
The best way would be to use a database, if I could.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to use onkeypress and/or onkeyup events instead.
   Did you know that there are plug-and-play auto-complete components out there that are free? For example http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/
2. Use JSON! It's much more compact. You'll probably save 30-40% on the size of that data.
   Did you know that you don't need to pass the whole data set for that to work? You can have it live on the server (e.g. in the database, or cached on the webserver for faster access and less db traffic), and have clients only pull small set of data at a time, based on characters that they type. That JQuery UI AutoComplete supports that feature.

---

If you cannot use JQuery and JQuery UI (not wanting would be an unacceptable answer), then I'm pretty sure there are other free alternatives, including this one: http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx